# Outlook 2007 Calendar - want to automate moving calendar a day ahead

Tags: microsoft-outlook, script, automation

I have a display board outside of a conference room that continuously shows an Outlook calendar for the conference room bookings.  Right now it requires that someone log onto the host pc and manually move the calendar view one day forward each day. Is there a script that could automate that?  Tahnk you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit brutal, but you could do the following:

1. Set outlook to start on the Calendar page:  `Tools / Options / Other / Advanced Options / Startup in this folder / Browse to calendar`
2. Create a batch file as below
3. Schedule the batch file created in (2) to run early each morning, say 1am.

What this will do is terminate outlook, and restart it.  Because it is set to Calendar as startup page, it will open on todays date in the calendar, in day view.

Batch file:

```
taskkill /im outlook.exe
outlook.exe
```

Comment: Wow, nice answser that was fast too.  Thank you Alpha Geek person!!!